# Location_Change action dispatched multiple times when navigating back using react redux router, immutablejs, and devtools

Tags: reactjs, redux, url-routing, immutability

After playing around with [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/tree/master/app), and implementing custom DevTools (not the browser plugin), I've noticed that when you navigate back, multiple LOCATION_CHANGE actions are fired. This will add an extra entry per new backwards navigation, so it starts of with 2, then 4, then 6, and so on. It's as if the entire browserHistory is being evaluated and emitting an action per item to list POP/PUSH/POP/PUSH/...

[image: location_change multiple fires]

In the actual DevTools inspector window, there is just the single action, despite the multiple console.log lines per action. If I commit the current set of items in DevTools, the count restarts... 2/4/6, etc.

Is this an expected side effect when utilizing DevTools? I ask because when I turn off the DevTools feature, I get one entry per navigation. Is it a matter with the routing mutating state in the custom routerReducer (via state.merge actually mutating, and just to deal with it)?

Here's a refresher of the code:

```
/** in app.js **************************/
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: selectLocationState(),
});


/** in selectors.js **************************/
const selectLocationState = () => {
  let prevRoutingState;
  let prevRoutingStateJS;

  return (state) => {
      const routingState = state.get('route'); // or state.route

      if (!routingState.equals(prevRoutingState)) {
          prevRoutingState = routingState;
          prevRoutingStateJS = routingState.toJS();
      }

      return prevRoutingStateJS;
  };
};

/** in reducers.js **************************/
function routeReducer(state = fromJS({
  locationBeforeTransitions: null,
}), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOCATION_CHANGE:
      console.log('location_change happened: ', action.payload)
      return state.merge({
        locationBeforeTransitions: action.payload,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function createReducer(asyncReducers) {
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer
  });
}

/** in store.js **************************/
if (DevTools) enhancers.push(DevTools.instrument());
```

I've compared this to our current side project which doesn't require special location state management (no redux-immutable or immutablejs), and we get the expected 1 log line per new location state, even when implementing the DevTools.

Thanks for any insight. Trying to make sure that I'm not fundamentally misunderstanding something.